# How to properly center two almost identical FontAwesome icons to the center of <button>?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to create toggle button with two centered FontAwesome icons: icon-microphone and icon-microphone-off. Unfortunatelly, when clicking the button, icon-microphone-off icon moves a bit to the left relative to the icon-microphone.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bchkM/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="btn1" class="btn"><i class="icon-microphone"></i></div>
```

CSS:

```
btn {
  width: 48px;
  min-height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #854eb3;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(changeIcon);
}

function changeIcon() {
    $(this).children().toggleClass("icon-microphone icon-microphone-off");
}
```

I've found a workaround (which I don't like much): just add 1px left margin for icon-microphone-off icon:

`.margin-1px-fix { margin-left: 1px; }`

Is there a better way to align both icon to the center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the size of the icon to an odd number. It's 1px off because the object you're trying to center probably isn't an even number of pixels wide.

```
.btn {
    width: 49px;
    min-height: 49px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #854eb3;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 49px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Taking your answer into account, I would make the line-height 49px assuming some other icons may be slightly different by a pixel.  +1

Comment: That's probably safe.  I have edited my code snippet above to reflect that.